# How does Java Spring could inject dependency with interface inheriting another interface?

Tags: java, spring, repository

I was trying to simulate the way that spring handle the injection of the Repository bean from another interface that inherits it

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<User> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(String emailAddress, String lastname);
}
```

so I'm wondering how do to inject TestImplimentation from TestTwo interface that extends Test:

[image]

```
@Configuration
public class DefBean {
    @Bean
    public Test test(){
        return new TestImplementation();
    }
}
```

but spring couldn't find **TestImplimentation** bean from **TestTwo** interface

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

Can you make it clear. If your asking about interface injection in spring.?